# How to get Visual Studio 2013 manually into safe mode?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, safe-mode

I know this might a common question. I don't really know why but my VS 2013 got really really slow yesterday. Every open VS is sucking up 25% of the CPU-Power. When I start it in the Safe Mode, everything is allright. So it has to be thrid party extensions.

1. I cann't figure out how to turn off all extensions. Via Tools/Extensions Updates I some extensions cannot be disabled or uninstalled (button disabled). Neither can I figure out what extension is malicious.
2. Will it even help to reinstall the VS?

thanks

Comment: The Proecess Monitor shows that devenv.exe always tries 2 processes: Operation: RegQuerKey Path: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default (Result SUCCESS) and  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicy\Default\policy.12.0.Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the command `devenv /setup` again via the commandline.

This Forces Visual Studio to (re-)merge the resource metadata that describes menus, toolbars, and command groups, from all available VSPackages.

The command must be run as an administrator. See also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx) and [Cleaning up the VS Environment when things go wrong](http://visualstudiohacks.com/tips/cleaning-up-the-vs-environment-when-things-go-wrong/)

I had the same problem with Resharper that slowed down my VS. Running the command fixed my problems.

Answer (score 1):

0) To answer the title of your question, you can launch VS in safe mode using the /SafeMode command-line switch: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx.

2) To reinstall VS without finding the root cause won't prevent the problem in the future.

1) The safe mode prevents loading 3rd party extensions, but then you can't enable them one by one to find the culprit. So you have to disable or to uninstall one by one:

- First, extensions can be mainly add-ins or packages (and MEF extensions).
- Add-ins can be unloaded in the Tools > Add-In Manager.
- Packages can be disabled (in some cases) or uninstalled (some of them require you to launch VS with admin rights, and some of them require you to use the Control Panel > Programs.
- If the package is 3rd party, you can reinstall it later. But if the package belongs to VS, you need to rerun the VS setup.
- There is another approach: Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) allows you to spy disk, registry and network activity, which may give a clue of the problem. And Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) allows you to select the devenv.exe process, select the Properties window and go to the Threads tab, which gives you the CPU usage per thread, maybe also a clue.